# Grid view Row Data Bound putting data in a particular cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have 3 tables `Customer`, `Address` and `Matching_Customer_Address`.

`Customer` has column `Name` and `Address` has column `City`. They have some other columns as well but I don't need them. The `Name` and the `City` column contains this kind of data.

```
   NAME                  City
----------             -----------
John                    New York
----------             ----------
Karin                   Hamburg
---------              ----------
Jona                    Tokyo
---------              ----------
Martin
```

`Matching_Customer_Address` contains the IDs of both tables which have a match between them.

I have a Grid view and I bind this `GridView1` with datatable `dt`. dt is in this format:
Data table dt first column is "Match" and rest of the columns are from `Address.City` and rows are from `Customer.Name`.

As Gridview1 is bind with dt so grid view is like this.

```
Match | New York| Hamburg | Tokyo  |
----- | --------| ------- | ------ |
John  |         |         |        |
----- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
Karin |         |         |        |
----- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
Jona  |         |         |        |
----- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
Martin|         |         |        |
----- | ------- | ------- | ------ |
```

Now by using the table `Matching_Customer_Address` I want to put a character "X" in `GridView1` cell. I am using `RowDataBound` event to do this task but I don't know how I should proceed.

I am trying to do

```
 e.Row.Cells[].Text = "X";
```

I know how to access the `Matching_Customer_Address` table here But I don't know how to put an X in a particular cell if a match is found. I am very new to C#.

Here is the code to bind data with gridview.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da_Customer, da_Address;
DataSet ds_Customer = new DataSet();
DataSet ds_Address = new DataSet();
SqlConnection con;
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");

da_Customer= new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name from Customer ", con);

da_Customer.Fill(ds_Customer, "Name");

da_Address = new SqlDataAdapter("Select City from Address ", con);

da_Address .Fill(ds_Address, "City");

int lengthofAddress = ds_Address.Tables[0].Select("City is not null").Length;
string[] getCols_City = new string[lengthofAddress];

int lengthofCustomer = ds_Customer.Tables[0].Select("Customer is not null").Length;
string[] getRows_Customer = new string[lengthofCustomer];


//added first column of dt.
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

// This loop is getting rows from table City and adding them as column of dt.
        for (int x = 0; x < (lengthofAddress); x++)
        {

   string mystring = (ds_Address.Tables[0].Rows[x]["City"].ToString());

            getRows_Customer[x] = mystring;
            dt.Columns.Add(getRows_Customer[x]);

        }

// This loop is getting rows from table Customer and adding them as Rows of dt.
        for (int x = 0; x < (lengthofCustomer); x++)
        {

         getRows_Customer[x] = (ds_Customer.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Name"].ToString());


            dt.Rows.Add(getRows_Customer[x]);

        }


        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Aspx Code is here :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC"
BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" Width="100%"
BorderStyle="None" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >

            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollHeader" /> 
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollItem" /> 
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollPager" /> 
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post your code, both code-behind and markup.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I have added the code in my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logic to find matches into the data table building logic that you posted, like this:

```
// This loop is getting rows from table Customer and adding them as Rows of dt.
for (int x = 0; x < (lengthofCustomer); x++)
{
    // Build the pieces of data for your row here

    // Name

    // Loop through each city
    for (int y = 0; y < (lengthofAddress); y++)
    {
        // Determine if each city is a match or not,
        // if so then put "X" in that row's cell here

    }
}
```

Now when you bind your grid with the data table, you will not need to handle the `RowDataBound` event, because the `X` will be in the right cell(s) already.

---

UPDATE:

To put values into a new data table row, you need to create a new row and then apply the cell values via the index of the row, like this:

```
DataRow row;

// Create new DataRow objects and add to DataTable.     
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    row = YourDataTable.NewRow();

    row["Name"] = theName;

    // Loop through each city
    for (int y = 0; y < (lengthofAddress); y++)
    {
        // Determine if each city is a match or not,
        // if so then put "X" in that row's cell here
        if(match)
        {
            row[y+1] = "X";
        }            
    }

    YourDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

UPDATE 2:

If the rows for each person in the match column already exist, then loop through each row like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in TheTable.Rows)
{
    // Loop through each city
    for (int y = 0; y < (lengthofAddress); y++)
    {
        // Determine if each city is a match or not,
        // if so then put "X" in that row's cell here
        if(match)
        {
            row[y+1] = "X";
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cami - that is the spot for you to put the logic that uses the IDs in the Matching_Customer_Address table to check against the current row's name and each city, hence the loop over the city names.

Comment: In the inner loop you gave a comment "// if so then put "X" in that row's cell here". I know I can add a row in dt how I can access a cell of dt.

Comment: Andersson I have checked your code it putting X in cells but its adding new rows to the data table at the end.

Comment: oh, so you have already created the rows for each person in the match column? I have updated the answer with another update to account for the rows already existing.

Comment: @Cami - see `UPDATE 2` in answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42221/discussion-between-cami-and-karl-anderson)